# How to provide ability to make code review using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

On my project we have repository and use TortoiseSVN for pulling, merging and branching code from there, but there is no code review like I was to have on previous job. I had BitBucket+SmartGit, and that was amazing. Now I also installed SmartGit and is able to pull and push code, but as I understand code review was on BitBucket, any advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code review is separate task, not directly related to VCS-client used. It's more question of selecting tool(s) and integration of client and selected tool

- [Post-commit code review](http://www.zealake.com/2011/12/30/lightweight-code-reviews-using-tortoisesvn/) with pure TSVN (a little cheat)
- [Review Board](https://www.reviewboard.org/) can be [integrated with SVN](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/rbt/commands/post/#cvs-and-subversion)

Comment: @Kamrad I have not the foggiest idea